# getActionBar() is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to add a ActionBar to my Fragment class, but I keep getting errors. This is my class:

```
public class TaskDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    MyTasks.taskItem mItem;

    public TaskDetailFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            mItem = MyTasks.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_detail,
                container, false);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();


        if (mItem != null) {
            //Add TexViews
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.in_Name))
                    .setText(MyTasks.customers[(Integer.parseInt(mItem.id))][1]);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.in_Address))
                    .setText(MyTasks.customers[(Integer.parseInt(mItem.id))][3] + "  " + MyTasks.customers[(Integer.parseInt(mItem.id))][2]);

        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is my error:

> The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type TaskDetailFragment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to ask the `Activity` (to which the `Fragment` has been attached) for the `ActionBar`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
```

Or if you're using the support library and/or ActionBarSherlock:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getFragmentActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

Fragments don't define a `getActionBar()` method, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that the getActionBar() is defined in the TaskDetailFragment or other superclasses or sometimes android emulataor can add "protected" to the defining of the method

Answer (score 0):

If a fragment wants to use ActionBar, it has to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` , usually from `onCreate()`.

Comment: If I call setHasOptionsMenu(true) I still got the same error.